# Objective-C Singleton Category for internal use of NSCalendar

Tags: objective-c, singleton, nscalendar, objective-c-category

I have a two part question. First, how can you create a Singleton category in Obj-C? It would just be for internal use so it does not have to be foolproof singleton. Secondly, can I create this category on NSCalendar and have the singleton be an autoupdatingCurrentCalendar? Is this safe considering a user might change timezones while using the application? I want to avoid creating an instance of NSCalendar each time I need one (since it is used for a tableviewcells) but I don't want to have timezone problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"singleton category" doesn't make any sense... A singleton is a class that can be instantiated no more than once. Categories provide a way to extend classes, but don't give you any particular control over how many times the class is instantiated.

It sounds like you really just want a shared instance of NSCalendar. If that's the case, then you can certainly declare a global variable and create some class methods in a category that give you access to that global variable.

Comment: In the strict sense of singleton, you're right. But `[NSFileManager defaultManager]` for example is also called a "singleton method" in the documentation, i.e. a method that always returns the same instance, even though it's possible to have more than one instance of `NSFileManager`.

Comment: @omz, I see that you're right, but you have to admit that using "singleton" to mean "shared object" is a harmful corruption of the term. If shared object is what's meant, say that. A singleton is very specifically a class that can be instantiated only once (or the one instance of such a class). I reported a bug against the NSFileManager docs and hope that you'll do the same.

Comment: Agreed, the documentation about singletons seems to be a bit inconsistent overall. The [conceptual document about singletons](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html) mentions `NSFileManager` as a "singleton class" with a `sharedFileManager` method that doesn't even exist...

Comment: The description of NSFileManager's -init method says that sending -init was undefined prior to 10.5, so it looks like NSFileManager *was* a singleton but isn't any longer.

Answer (score 0):

`autoupdatingCurrentCalendar` is already a singleton, so I don't see the point of creating a category for that. As for creating singleton categories – sure, that's possible, pretty much the same as a regular singleton.

Comment: Where is it documented that it is a singleton? I haven't been able to find that, but it definitely makes sense...

Comment: Frankly, I just assumed it would always (except for timezone changes) return the same instance, but I just tested that and it's apparently not the case...